# Implicit `resolve` in JavaScript promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, es6-promise

I'm using promises in JavaScript with `setTimeout` and I'm getting something of a mysterious behaviour. I'm seeing things working fine and I can't explain it.

Let's say I have this function:

```
function f(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => callback(13), 3000);
}
```

When I call it with no callback, I get a most expected error:

```
> f()
undefined
> Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function
```

When I call it with an actual callback, all works fine:

```
> f(console.log)
undefined
> 13
```

## The *«problem»*

So far, all went according to plan, but when I call `f()` wrapped in a promise, it seems to no longer require the `callback` parameter:

```
> new Promise(f).then(console.log)
Promise { <pending> }
> 13
```

Going a bit slower, if I store the promise, it ends up having a value:

```
> p = new Promise(f)
Promise { <pending> }
> p
Promise { <pending> }
> p // after 3 seconds
Promise { 13 }
>
```

This happens on both browser and Node.

**QUESTION:** How is it possible that `f` doesn't complain at all for the lack of a `callback`? How is the value `13` assigned as the promise value?

`TL;DR === false` I know I should be counting my blessings because it's working, but documentation doesn't seem to mention any hidden default mechanism for dealing with this kind of situation that I could find. All I get is a brief intro immediately followed by a fast-forward pathway into chaining and more advanced patterns. I need to be sure that I can replicate this behaviour with more complex cases.

Comment: the callback is resolved by `resolve` method - if you are passing pointer to method to the `new Promise` it will receive 2 arguments - resolve and reject. Try to `console.log(arguments)` inside `f` function

Answer (score 3):

> How is it possible that f doesn't complain at all for the lack of a callback?

The function you give to a promise *does* receive arguments: `resolve` and `reject` callbacks.

A normal use of promises look like this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // call resolve() on success
  // call reject() on error
});
```

> How is the value 13 assigned as the promise value?

You're calling `resolve(13)` when your timeout expires.

Answer (score 3):

Lets move f to the promise constructor ...

```
new Promise(function f(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => callback(13), 3000);
}).then(console.log)
```

Then lets add another argument ...

```
new Promise(function f(callback, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => callback(13), 3000);
}).then(console.log)
```

And rename callback to resolve:

```
new Promise(function f(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(13), 3000);
}).then(console.log)
```

Does it look familiar?